# Why use commands in MVVM

Tags: .net, mvvm, icommand

I'm actually learning MVVM pattern.

I can't understand one thing about commands. Why use them? Why don't just use a function (in the `View`) which call a `ViewModel`'s function? What commands provide us? Apparently they are widely used, but i can't find why.

Comment: You use commands to execute delegates from your *view* to your *view model*, not from your *viewmodel* to your *model*. Your model should mainly be your POCO's, while your `ViewModel` holds most of the logic invoked by your views.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Not really. Logic can go inside model also.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I love it when you say not really on opinion based things :) It's a matter of flavor, your `Model` can have logic, I didn't say it can't. I said *most*, because that's how I view the it.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov No matter who holds logic, Model or ViewModel, why use commands to "invoke" logic?

Comment: @ZwoRmi See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952956/wpf-commands-vs-events-advantages-disadvantages) to answer your question. I think it may actually be a duplicate.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov The [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2953060/4632606) provides explantion but the questions aren't the same, questions was about advantages/disadvantages.

Comment: Because `OnButtonClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) { (this.DataContext as MyViewModel).OnButtonClicked(); }` is a dirty filthy hack, not to mention browsing the visual tree to locate whatever `CommandParameter` should be.  Why debase yourself when a much easier alternative exists?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why use commands?

Because commands provide encapsulation. You can hide any kind of complex logic inside a `ICommand` and you can swap the implementation whenever you need. So that your View doesn't need to know anything about your methods of ViewModel etc. It just needs to know ViewModel provides a command to do operation "x".

More than that `ICommand` interface is supported by many framework elements like `Button`, `MenuItem` etc. When you have a `ICommand` you can bind it to the View --it will take care of executing the command.

> Why don't just use a function (in the View) which call a ViewModel's
>   function?

Because we don't want to mix up the responsibilities. View shouldn't have any logic, it is just a dumb thing which just displays the data to the user. No more.

Assume if you have logic in your view. One day your manager can come up and say we don't need this UI anymore(it doesn't looks good). Make it something attractive. Not only the View have to be redesigned, but you need to repeat the logic in View there. This is repeated work(against DRY principle), can introduce new bugs because your UI has changed etc.

Another main advantage of separating the View and Logic is that you can easily unittest the Logic (in ViewModel and Model).

Comment: Great explanation. And if i've understand, the `ViewModel` provides the command, and there is no need to create a function in the `View` code behind. Am i right?

Comment: @ZwoRmi Exactly. When you know there will be a command in `ViewModel` you don't need code behind for view and you can unittest the viewmodel directly. If the binding is correct, then you don't have to test the UI.

Comment: But then why not just have the View bound to **methods** in the ViewModel rather than the **command**. I get this is how the language is designed to work, but why add this extra layer?

Answer (score 2):

Another benefit from using `ICommand` is its `bool CanExecute()` method. You can monitor and control the state and define conditions when your `ICommand` can and will be invoked. Plus, for example, `Button` with bound `ICommand` disables itself automatically, if `CanExecute()` returns false (do not forget to call `CanExecuteChanged()` method of ICommand every time the propert(y/ies), which affect(s) `CanExecute()`, change(s) its/their value).
By the way, the semantic of usage of this pattern is described in other answers.

Comment: but don't forget to raise `CanExecuteChanged` and/or call `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested` if needed when you change a property that influences `CanExecute()`...

Comment: @eFloh, definitely and obviously. Edited the answer.